# Mismatched -init method names

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I discovered an odd scenario that produces a compiler warning in XCode that I don't believe is a valid warning.

As an example I created two classes, ClassA & ClassB, that both have an init method called -initWithSomething:
One takes an (NSDate *) as the "something" and the other takes (NSString *)

**Class A**

```
// ClassA.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
}
-(id)initWithSomething:(NSDate *)something;
@end

// ClassA.m
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA
-(id)initWithSomething:(NSDate *)something {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**Class B**

```
// ClassB.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
}
-(id)initWithSomething:(NSString *)something;
@end

// ClassB.m
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB
-(id)initWithSomething:(NSString *)something {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**Implementation of another class that uses both ClassA & ClassB**

```
#import "ExampleClass.h"
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ExampleClass

-(void)doSomething {
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"];

    ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] initWithSomething:date];
    ClassB *classB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithSomething:string]; // Produces "Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSDate *'
    ClassB *classB2 = [[ClassB alloc] initWithSomething:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"]]; // Does NOT produce a warning
    ClassB *classB3 = [[ClassB alloc] initWithSomething:@"Test"]; // Produces the same warning as above.

    [classA release];
    [classB release];
    [classB2 release];
    [classB3 release];
}
```

Is this a compiler bug?  Doesn't seem like either of those lines should produce a warning, especially since the line where "classB2" is initted produces no warnings.
This code actually works fine, the correct class' -initWithSomething: is called and passed the appropriate type of argument.

Clearly, more explicit method names will avoid the issue but I'd like to know why the compiler isn't able to handle this.

**Note**:
I should add that this only seems to occur with -init methods, any other instance or class functions do not seem to produce the warning.

Comment: I dont know why someone would downvote this, this is a great question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `+alloc` returns a generic `id`.

This means that any method can be called on it, and the compiler will see that the first method imported that has the signature `-initWithSomething` is for class `A`, which expects an object of type `NSDate *`.

Also, I do believe that the method `+stringWithFormat` returns an `id` which can be compatible with `NSDate`.

**EDIT:**

A simple solution to this problem:

```
@interface ClassA

+(ClassA *) typeSafeAlloc;

// ...
@end

@implementation ClassA

+(ClassA *) typeSafeAlloc
{
    // self is the class variable,  which is the same as:
    // return [ClassA alloc];
    return [self alloc];
}
@end
```

And repeat the process with ClassB (with typeSafeAlloc returning a `ClassB` object)

Answer (score 2):

alloc return an object of type id and therefore the compiler assumes that `initWithSomething` belongs to `Class A` (The first class interface it encounters that has the method name).

Somthing like 
`[(ClassB*)[ClassB alloc] initWithSomething:string];` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the return type of `+stringWithFormat`

> Returns a string created by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.
>
> `+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`

(from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

The compiler knows string is an `NSString*`, same with `@"literals"`. An `id` however, could be anything (even an `NSSDate*`).